# How get the data from another file using $http service in angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to get the data from the another html file using angularjs $http get method, but i did't get anything

below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head ng-app="myApp">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
                <p>{{welcome}}</p><br />
                <h1>{{error}}</h1>
            </div>
                <script>
                    var app=angular.module('myApp',[])
                    app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
                        $http.get('home.html').than(function(response){
                            $scope.welcome=response.data;
                        },function(reason){
                            $scope.error=reason.data;
                        });
                    }]);
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Below is my another html file code

```
<p>This is home page</p>
```

Comment: you are accessing html page via $http ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `then` not `than`

```
.then(function(response){
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/nhCA84InCt8bPMfLiL8z?p=preview)